# Difference in std::map behavior between debug and release builds (Xcode 8.3, C++ 11, Cocos2d-x)

Tags: xcode, c++11, stl, cocos2d-x, release

Running into an unexpected difference in behavior between a debug build built in Xcode 8.3.3, C++11, on the Cocos2d-x framework. I'm using the emplace() method to populate an std::map (_randomLetterChancesToAppear), which is correctly being built in debug, but appears not to be populated in release. This assertion is being tripped at a time when the two values are expected to be equal:

```
CC_ASSERT(outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.size() == alphabetCount);
```

When the assert trips in a release build, _randomLetterChancesToAppear doesn't appear to contain any data. *(To test this, in case it's relevant, I created a duplicate Xcode scheme to my default mobile scheme, and changed the Run build configuration to release to allow me to test a release build with the IDE attached.)*

Here's the offending method:

```
void GameDataController::PopulateIndividualCellChancesToAppear(CellDetail &outCellDetail, const rapidjson::Value &cellDetailObject, const GameDetail& constGameDetail) const
{
    cocostudio::DictionaryHelper* dicTool = cocostudio::DictionaryHelper::getInstance();
    CC_ASSERT(dicTool->checkObjectExist_json(cellDetailObject, "LetterChancesToAppear"));
    CCASSERT(constGameDetail._alphabet.length() > 0, "Zero-length alphabet!");

    const rapidjson::Value& letterChancesObject = dicTool->getSubDictionary_json(cellDetailObject, "LetterChancesToAppear");

    // iterate through each letter in this game detail's alphabet
    const int alphabetCount = static_cast<int>(constGameDetail._alphabet.length());
    std::vector<char> lettersNeedingChances;
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabetCount; ++i)
    {
        // if a given alphabet letter has a chance to appear, save it.
        const char alphabetChar = constGameDetail._alphabet.at(i);
        char letterChanceKey[1];
        sprintf(letterChanceKey, "%c", alphabetChar);
        if (dicTool->checkObjectExist_json(letterChancesObject, letterChanceKey))
        {
            const float ChanceToAppear = dicTool->getFloatValue_json(letterChancesObject, letterChanceKey);
            CC_ASSERT(!std::isnan(ChanceToAppear));
            CC_ASSERT(ChanceToAppear >= 0.0f);
            outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.emplace(alphabetChar, !std::isnan(ChanceToAppear) ? ChanceToAppear : 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            // ... otherwise, store the letter in a list of letters without assigned chances.
            lettersNeedingChances.push_back(alphabetChar);
        }
    }

    // fill in missing chances to appear.
    if (lettersNeedingChances.size() > 0)
    {
        float defaultRemainingChance = 1.0f / static_cast<float>(alphabetCount);
        CC_ASSERT(!std::isnan(defaultRemainingChance));
        CC_ASSERT(defaultRemainingChance > FLT_EPSILON);
        for (const char remainingChar : lettersNeedingChances)
        {
            CCLOG("Character %c doesn't have a chance to appear specified. Using default %f", remainingChar, defaultRemainingChance);
            outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.emplace(remainingChar, defaultRemainingChance);
        }
    }
    // vvvv THIS ASSERT IS FAILING IN RELEASE, BUT NOT IN DEBUG BUILD CONFIGURATIONS. vvvvv
    CC_ASSERT(outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.size() == alphabetCount);

    // normalize chances to appear.
    float chanceTotal = 0.0f;
    for(auto iterator = outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.begin();
        iterator != outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.end();
        iterator++)
    {
        chanceTotal += iterator->second;
    }

    if (std::abs(chanceTotal - 1.0f) > FLT_EPSILON)
    {
        float adjustmentFactor = 1.0f / chanceTotal;
        float adjustedChanceTotal = 0.0f;
        for(auto iterator = outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.begin();
            iterator != outCellDetail._randomLetterChancesToAppear.end();
            iterator++)
        {
            iterator->second = iterator->second * adjustmentFactor;
            adjustedChanceTotal += iterator->second;
        }
        CCASSERT(std::abs(adjustedChanceTotal - 1.0f) <= FLT_EPSILON, "adjustedChanceTotal != 1.0f");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this method might be behaving differently between the two build configurations?

Comment: His is likely undefined behavior aka. UB. You should try and use a tool like valgrind, Xcode probably have something similar. This can tell you tings such as: if you are using uninitialized memory or writing to memory that isn't allocated. There are numerous other tools to use in the hunt for this kind of bugs.

Comment: `char letterChanceKey[1]; sprintf(letterChanceKey, "%c", alphabetChar);` This exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun. `letterChanceKey` doesn't have room for the terminating NUL.

Comment: Thank you so much Igor! Increasing the buffer size appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) for the answer.

```
    char letterChanceKey[1];
    sprintf(letterChanceKey, "%c", alphabetChar);
```

did not leave enough room for the terminating NUL and caused a buffer overrun. Increasing the buffer size fixed the problem.

Thank you Igor!